# Integrating a linear function with values from another function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Lets say I have a function like this and call it $f(\lambda)$:

[image]

And I have another function, that is linear: $y_1=K*a$ where $a$ in this function is known and it is a constant.

Now, how would I get a sum (lets call it $S$) of values of $y_1$ from $\lambda_1$ to $\lambda_2$ where its $K=\frac{f(\lambda)}{Y_0}$?

I've tried the obvious: $S=\frac{K*a}{Y_0}\int_{\lambda_1}^{\lambda_2}{f(\lambda)}$ And its not working, ofcourse...